# Why is wp_dropdown_categories not searching within the sub-categories in my custom taxonomy

Tags: search

The search is not working as how I intend for it to work. As of now when the dropdown is selected as "ALL" it searches the entire taxonomy/site but when a user searches and selects a "sub category" from the dropdown it doesn't search for the term inside that "sub category" of my dropdown instead it searches the term throughout the site.

What I want it to do is when a sub category is selected to search for the term inside that selected category.

Custom taxonomy name = `asset_categories`

Custom post type name = `assets`

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
<form role="search" method="get" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">

<div class="search-text-options">
  <div class="search-text">
    <input 
      type="search" 
        placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Find the asset you need...', 'placeholder' ) ?>"
        value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" name="s"
        title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) ?>">
  </div><!-- eo // .search-text -->

  <div class="search-sort">
    <span>View by:</span>
       <?php
        if ( is_page('brand-principles') || has_term( 'brand-principles', 'asset_categories' )) {
         $args = array(
                'show_option_none' => __( 'All' ),
                'echo'             => 0,
                'hierarchical'     => 1,
                'depth'            => 2,
                'child_of'         => 33,
                'taxonomy'         => 'asset_categories',
                'value_field'      => 'taxonomy',
        );
       } else if ( is_page('digital') || has_term( 'digital', 'asset_categories' )) {
         $args = array(
                'show_option_none' => __( 'All' ),
                'echo'             => 0,
                'hierarchical'     => 1,
                'depth'            => 2,
                'child_of'         => 34,
                'taxonomy'         => 'asset_categories',
                'value_field'      => 'taxonomy',
        );
       } else if ( is_page('print') || has_term( 'print', 'asset_categories' ) ) {
            $args = array(
                'show_option_none' => __( 'All' ),
                'echo'             => 0,
                'hierarchical'     => 1,
                'depth'            => 2,
                'child_of'         => 35,
                'taxonomy'         => 'asset_categories',
                'value_field'      => 'taxonomy',
            );
       } else if ( is_page('visual-identity') || has_term( 'visual-identity', 'asset_categories' )) {
            $args = array(
                'show_option_none' => __( 'All' ),
                'echo'             => 0,
                'show_count'       => 1,
                'hierarchical'     => 1,
                'depth'            => 2,
                'child_of'         => 66,
                'taxonomy'         => 'asset_categories',
                'value_field'      => 'taxonomy',
            );
       } else {
            $args = array(
                'show_option_none' => __( 'All' ),
                'show_count'       => 1,
                'echo'             => 0,
                'hierarchical'     => 1,
                'depth'            => 1,
                'taxonomy'         => 'asset_categories',
                'value_field'      => 'taxonomy',
            );
       }

      ?>

      <?php $select  = wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?>
      <?php $replace = "<select$1>"; ?>
      <?php $select  = preg_replace( '#<select([^>]*)>#', $replace, $select ); ?>

      <?php echo $select; ?>


  </div><!-- eo // .search-sort -->
</div><!-- eo // .search-text-options -->

<div class="search-submit">
  <input type="submit" class="search-submit-button"
    value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button' ) ?>" />
</div><!-- eo // .submit -->
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your intention is. You use term and category separately, but they are the same thing. Do you want it to display *posts* with the selected term? You have `value_field` set to `taxonomy`, which is a bit confusing here.

Comment: what ever is inside the input search field is what should be searched inside the 'sub category' @Milo

Comment: yes so when the term `logo` is searched and the sub category of `visual` is selected it should return the posts under the custom post type `assets`